# Python: What is the best way to realize load balancing in multiprocessing when using chunk

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For example, to distribute 17 tasks to 2 process in chunk of 6 will be 2*6+5, that is to say, each process got 6, but there is remaining 5 tasks. I think the best way is for remaining tasks evenly distribute across 2 process. So I did a test to see if `mp.Pool` is doing this way. Here is a testing script

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(mp.current_process())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = mp.Pool(2)
    p.map(f, range(17),6)
```

will output

```
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
```

notice the last 5 lines, it is clearly that the remaining tasks all distributed to one process, then all the other process has nothing to do.

Is there a good way to auto distribute the remaining chunk in `Pool.map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with a simple parameter variation. And you do not reallocate processes either when they have been assigned to a worker.

Of course you can write a workaround:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = mp.Pool(2)
    tasks = 17
    chunksize = 6

    p.map(f, range((tasks / chunksize) * chunksize), 6)
    p.map(f, range((tasks / chunksize) * chunksize + 1, tasks))
```

This does the full chunks first. The remaining five tasks are then assigned to the pool one by one instead of in chunks. This will now produce the desired result.

I am not sure why this is important, though. If tasks take a long time to complete, what is the point of using chunks? There would not be any performance uplift as time would be spent in workers. You would do absolutely fine with the default chunk size of 1 and just allocate a task to a worker as soon as one becomes free.

Chunksize could give a performance uplift if tasks complete in a minuscule amount of time and more time would be spent in transferring data to workers one by one. If this is the case, then it does not really matter if the last tasks are completed by one worker only as time to complete these few tasks will be insignificant.

This particular example is of course the worst case scenario. In a more realistic scenario, as often as not, there would not be any performance loss. Imagine a batch of tens of thousands of tasks sent to workers in chunks of 35. Inevitably, during the batch process, the workers diverge and they do not finish exactly the same time. Some chunks will be faster and some slower. Let us now assume your remainder is not 34 but 17.  If worker A has now started the last full chunk and has processed less than a half of the tasks when worker B finishes its last full chunk and gets the remainder of 17, it would be likely that worker B actually completes before worker A despite having processed the remainder set.

But if there is a reason to do chunks first and the remainder distributed to workers, then this would be the way to do it. I do think that you are trying to solve a problem that is not a problem, though, and you would just be adding more complexity to your code for the sake of performance gain that is hard to measure.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I might leave the workaround till last since it's not the main thrust of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for patient explanation. +1